# Manage QWidgets' action lists in Designer / Creator?

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, qt-designer, qwidget

Is it possible to manage the list of a given widget's actions directly in Designer and/or Creator's UI Editor? Creator 4.14.0, Windows.

By "widget's actions" I mean the ones set with e.g. [`QWidget::addAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction).

Right now I just set up any action lists explicitly in the window's constructor, but it would be nice if I could just manage the list in the GUI. I poked around in the UI editor's various context menus and in the Action Editor pane, but didn't see anything. I couldn't find anything in the Properties pane either.

Comment: Have you tried Action editor? It is placed near Signal\slot editor in Qt Designer

Comment: @jdfa Yeah that's what I use to manage the QActions themselves, and it's what I meant by "action editor pane"; but as far as I can tell it doesn't have a thing for adding / removing those actions to a given QWidget... or does it? I just looked again and I don't *see* anything (but I'm bad at noticing things).

Comment: you can add and remove actions there: https://i.imgur.com/RD17K9l.png

Comment: @jdfa Yeah; that just creates the QActions themselves (as members of the generated Ui object), but it doesn't add them to any widgets. Here's an example use case that might clarify: Say you have a `QLineEdit` and you set its `contextMenuPolicy` to `ActionsContextMenu`. You could create `someAction` in the Action Editor, but then in code you still have to do e.g. `ui->theLineEdit->addAction(ui->someAction)`. That last `QWidget::addAction` step is what I'm wondering if Designer can do. The Action Editor only takes care of the `ui->someAction = new QAction(...)` part of that. :)